# Laravel Eloquent Filtering Results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my controller I retrieve a list of messages from the message model. I am trying to add a filter, but the filters are cancelling each other out.

```
// Controller
public function __construct(Message $messages)
{
    $this->messages = $messages;
}

public function index($filter = null)
{
    $messages = $this->messages
        ->actioned($filter == 'actioned' ? false : true)
        ->ignored($filter == 'ignored' ? true : false)
        ->get();

    return view('...
}

// Model
public function scopeActioned($query, $actioned = true)
{
    $constraint = ($actioned ? 'whereNotNull' : 'whereNull');

    return $query->$constraint('ts_actioned');
}

public function scopeIgnored($query, $ignored = true)
{
    return $query->where('is_ignored', ($ignored ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
}
```

How can I setup Eloquent so that scopeActioned is only called if $filter is set to 'actioned', and the same for ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple Approach:**

```
public function index($filter = null)
{
    $query = $this->messages->query();
    //applying filter
    if($filter == 'actioned') {
        $query->actioned();
    }
    if($filter == 'ignored') {
        $query->ignored();
    }

    $messages = $query->get();

    return view('...
}
```

**Another Approach is work in Scope Function.**

```
// Model
public function scopeActioned($query, $actioned = true)
{
    if($actioned) {
        $query->whereNotNull('ts_actioned');
    }

    return $query;
}

public function scopeIgnored($query, $ignored = true)
{
    if($ignored) {
        $query->where('is_ignored', 'Yes');
    }

    return $query;
}
```